# How to make temporary table with row for each of last 24 hours?

Tags: sql

Basically, I want query that would generate result with a row for each hour in last 24 hours:

```
01/01/2011 00:00:00
01/01/2011 01:00:00
01/01/2011 02:00:00
...
```

Any way I can do that without cursors and temp tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One row for each hour for a given date (SQL Server solution).

```
select dateadd(hour, Number, '20110101')
from master..spt_values
where type = 'P' and
      number between 0 and 23
```

> result with a row for each hour in last 24 hours

```
select dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, getdate()) - number, 0)
from master..spt_values
where type = 'P' and
      number between 0 and 23
```

Comment: +1 for direct use of (undocumented) spt_values. I knew I had done something very like this somewhere in the past, but could I remember how or where ? The "type = 'P'" bit is the key.

Answer (score 3):

Well... on SQL Server you could do this...

```
WITH cte
AS
(
  SELECT CAST('1-jan-2011' AS DATETIME) AS 'date'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(hh, 1, [date]) FROM cte WHERE [date] < '1-jan-2011 23:00'
)
SELECT [date] FROM cte
```

...but in reality, a table with just the hours *(0 to 23)* would be more useful, because you could then add the hour to any date.

```
WITH cte
AS
(
  SELECT 0 as 'Hour'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT hour + 1 FROM cte WHERE hour < 23
)
SELECT DateAdd(hh, hour, '1-jan-2010') FROM cte
```

Another, slightly more isoteric way would be to use the row_number ranking function against the first 24 rows of some abitrary object (like spt_values)...

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT n
  FROM ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY type ) FROM master..spt_values ) D ( n )
  WHERE n < 24
)
SELECT dateadd(hh,n,'01-jan-2011') FROM cte
```

Comment: Does `ROW_NUMBER()` start from `0` ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simple way...

```
SELECT '01/01/2011 00:00:00' as [hour], blah, blah2
UNION ALL
SELECT '01/01/2011 01:00:00' as [hour], blah, blah2
UNION ALL
SELECT '01/01/2011 02:00:00' as [hour], blah, blah2
UNION ALL
...etc 24 times.
```

On a particular platform or solving a particular problem there might be a better way, but you will have to give more detail to get that answer.